# Application on Mono stopped working properly

Tags: c#, mono

I am running a .Net application under Mono for months now. I did an `apt-get upgrade` and then after trying to run the application I get `NullReference unhandled`-exceptions in class constructors. I removed and reinstalled Mono with no luck.

It seems to throw these exceptions when trying to run code from Referenced Libraries (Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose). I don't know if or why the libraries are not loaded correctly anymore. There are no other error message and I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

From

[GitHub Raspberry-Sharp Issues Page](https://github.com/raspberry-sharp/raspberry-sharp-system/issues/6)

> it looks like recent kernels have changed the way the processor is reported.

The page also shows the solution, which involves manual changes and rebuild of the library.